# Data table with all combinations

Tags: r, data.table

I am dealing with a problem. I have a one row data table and approx. 60 columns. Values in each columns are sampled, so that each cell has: two (YES, NO) or five (A, B, C, D, E) values. My question is how to add rows in such way, that all table will have all possible combinations ? Is expand.grid together with mapply a good choice or maybe, there is a better way to do this ?

Comment: `CJ(c("YES", "NO"), c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"))`. Note that if you have sixty columns you'll have an enormous amount of rows (>10^28) if each column has 3 possible value...

Comment: `CJ` is the `data.table`-canonical way to do it I believe as sindri_baldur demonstrated. An equivalent alternative (that may be faster at times but produces effectively the same output) could be `do.call(expand.grid, list(c("YES", "NO"), c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")))`. In this example, it's approximately 5x faster than `CJ`, not sure how that comparison will scale. (Note that by default this creates `factor`s.)